# Handle Post request to React JS app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, react-router, react-router-v4

I have written a whole application in ReactJS Client Side. I am able to accept /API on my react app URL using `<BrowserRouter>`

I am looking for a way to make a post request to my React App. Eg. When a user makes a post request to http://myreactapp.com , it should recognize the Post request and get the Post Body received from this call and I want to assign it one of the state before the React App loads.

I tried searching many things on BrowserRouter but I am not able to find 1.

Can someone help me direct towards the way to implement handling POST with body params.

I am open to only suggestions too and and not the whole code since I am kind of stuck thinking what to do next.

```
render((
<BrowserRouter>
    <div>
        <Route exact path="/"
            render={() => (<App />)} />
        <Route path="/find/:find"
            render={(props) => (<App {...props} />)} />
    </div>
</BrowserRouter>
), document.getElementById('root')
);
```

I tried with BorwserRouter but it seems it only accepts Get parameters and not Post body.

I have also heard of using NodeJS or express as the backend but can someone help me with modifying my current React code to convert to Express only for Post request and remaining everything remains same,

TIA!

Comment: Hmmm, the question is really confusing. `BrowserRouter` doesn't handle requests. It basically syncs browser URL state to application navigation state. It works with HTML5 History API that doesn't involve requests per se. It is your server that handles requests not "ReactJS Client Side"